# heroku can't detect buildpack

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I have a Flask app that I am trying to put on heroku. I have a requirements.txt file with the requirements for my project, and heroku says that this should be enough to let heroku detect python but it does not. I can manually set the buildpack to python like so
`heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python` but then I get this error: (from running `git push heroku master`)

```
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
No default language could be detected for this app.`
```

What is wrong with my project layout?

Here is my file tree:

```
.
├── faceParser
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── recolor.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── libs
│   │   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   │   │   ├── bootstrap.min.js
│   │   │   ├── jquery.min.js
│   │   │   ├── notify.js
│   │   │   └── webcam.min.js
│   │   ├── sketch.js
│   │   └── style.css
│   └── templates
│       ├── base.html
│       └── index.html
├── main.sh
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
└── venv
```

(virtual environment files omitted because there are a lot of them)

This is how I run it locally:

```
export FLASK_APP=faceParser
export FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I changed my project layout to contain an app.py file in the outermost directory, and added a Procfile file and a runtime.txt file (python-3.5.2)

I think that Heroku needs these files to understand that it is a python project.

Now it works.